# remove first letter (prefix) of the command message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so i am currently making the error handles for my discord bot, and when it returns that it has not all arguments, this is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    await ctx.send(f'❓ it seems like your entry `{ctx.message.content}` **does not contain all needed arguments!** try `+help {ctx.message.content.split()[0]}` for more info!')
```

as you can see, i want the user to be able to see a `+help [COMMAND EXECUTED WITHOUT PREFIX]` in the response, how would i do that? everything works, it‘s just the prefix in the `ctx.message.content.split()[0]` that i don‘t want to be there..
thanks in advance! [(and btw, the response message is attached as picture!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYDNB.jpg)

Comment: Slice it (`.split()[0][1:]`), perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [`ctx.command.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Command.name) attribute:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    command = ctx.command.name
    await ctx.send(f'❓ it seems like your entry `{ctx.message.content}` **does not contain all needed arguments!** try `+help {command}` for more info!')
```